# uninitialized constant LoginController in Ruby. 

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie in Ruby. I installed by following this tutorial: `http://udooz.net/blog/2011/02/facebook-app-using-rails-koala/`

Now, when I do this: rails generate controller

rails generate controller home index

I get this error:

```
/home/hiccup-pro/Documents/qstack/config/environment.rb:8:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
from /home/hiccup-pro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
from /home/hiccup-pro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
from /home/hiccup-pro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I fixed it. Atleast that bug, but now I've a different bug and that is: uninitialized constant LoginController. I googled a bit and found out that I should not mention config.* in the environment.rb. 
Anyway, 
this is my environment.rb

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Qack::Application.initialize!
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
```

So, why do I get this `uninitialized constant LoginController` error?

Comment: Could you post your environment.rb file?

Comment: Also which version of Rails do you use?

Comment: I too faced this kind of issue while integrating facebook application, but could not fix it. Then I ended up using 'facebooker2' gem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your environment.rb is hard to say, but my best shoot is that you put the code

```
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
config.gem "koala"
```

Outside of the block

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  ....
end
```

That is inside of environment.rb. If there is no such a block add it like this:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
  config.gem "koala"
end
```

Comment: It seems that if I use config.gem "koala" in the enviroment.rb, it will give me a uninitialized constant LoginController. It is giving me the error, I removed the code but still the bug is not solved.

Comment: Well your initial answer is fixed isnt it? In any case you have to show us the entire error not only one line

Comment: Not quite. What you said works for Rails 2.3 but not >3 versions.